# Naming convention for path elements

Tags: javascript, path, naming-conventions

I'm actually looking for a good path convention and mostly where to store `/` between elements:

- At the end of the directory `const dir = "example/"`
- At the start of the following element `const file = "/example1.md"`
- None of them (allow to use `Array.join('/')`)

I was looking into the [URL convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) to try to find a good practice but it didn't talk about the path.

**Example**

Let's see into a real example

```
const base_url = process.env.API_URL // http://localhost:3000(/)
const endpoint_path = "(/)users/auth(/)" 
const endpoint_name = "(/)tfa-validation"

// Slash before of after
let path = base_url + endpoint_path + endpoint_name; 
// Or without slash
path = `${base_url}/${endpoint_path}/${endpoint_name}`; 
path = [base_url, endpoint_path, endpoint_name].join('/')
```

Do a convention already exist ? Do a solution have any advantage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any convention for this.
So, my opinion is:

1. Do not use '/' either in the endpoint path or name. Keep them clean because you may want to use those variables isolated;
2. Use the join function because is cleaner.

---

```
const base_url = process.env.API_URL // http://localhost:3000
const endpoint_path = "users/auth" 
const endpoint_name = "tfa-validation"

path = [base_url, endpoint_path, endpoint_name].join('/')
```

Comment: I read the GNU Unix documentation about path into variable and it's preferred to not include `/` on path but keep them clean as you say. So I think this is the best solution for web too.